# Is there a binary equivalent of System.Text.StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, binary

I'm concatenating a large number of byte[] arrays in C#.  If I were doing this for strings, I would use StringBuilder -- is there an equivalent class that would work for binary data in byte[] arrays?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there is an exact equivalent, but you could get it done with a BinaryWriter:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(m);
writer.Write(true);
writer.Write("hello");
writer.Write(12345);
writer.Flush();
return m.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write them into a MemoryStream, perhaps using a StreamWriter/BinaryWriter. If endian-ness is an issue, some of the classes [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) might help